# How to compile js, css at the public dir not the app/assets in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compilation, assets

I have some HTML page in my Rails project /public dir, and these HTML pages should include some js, css files also in the /public, such as /public/js, /public/css, /public/images.

My question is how to compile these assets in the /public dir except move them to /app/assets/.

Answer (score 1):

The compiled css and js files truly in public/ not app/assets!
Make sure that your Rails env is `production` instead of `development`

Comment: I am sorry, the expression is not clear. I know that the assets in the  app/assets will be precompile into public/assets when the Rails env is production. I means I have some js files in the public/my_js/, how can I compile them. Such as I have public/my_js/a.js, public/my_js/b.js. how can I compile a.js and b.js.

Comment: In production.rb, try to add your js files to this:
# config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )